# Setting domain based on data extent

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple d3 area chart, with two areas plotted using the following data:

```
var data =  [
  [{'year':0,'amount':2},{'year':1,'amount':3},{'year':2,'amount':9},{'year':3,'amount':5},{'year':4,'amount':6},{'year':5,'amount':7},{'year':6,'amount':8},{'year':7,'amount':9},{'year':8,'amount':10},{'year':9,'amount':11},{'year':10,'amount':12}],
  [{'year':0,'amount':1},{'year':1,'amount':2},{'year':2,'amount':8},{'year':3,'amount':4},{'year':4,'amount':5},{'year':5,'amount':6},{'year':6,'amount':7},{'year':7,'amount':8},{'year':8,'amount':9},{'year':9,'amount':10},{'year':10,'amount':11}]
];
```

The two separate arrays of objects allow me to plot two areas on one chart using the code below:

```
var colors = [
  'steelblue',
  'lightblue',
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d,i) { console.log(d); return d[i].year; })))
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 16])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
  .tickSize(-height)
  .tickPadding(10)  
  .tickSubdivide(true)  
    .orient("bottom");  

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
  .tickPadding(10)
  .tickSize(-width)
  .tickSubdivide(true)  
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "axis-label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
  .attr("x", -height/2)
  .text('Axis Label');  

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);





//************************************************************
// Create D3 line object and draw data on our SVG object
//************************************************************
var line = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("cardinal")  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.amount); });   

svg.selectAll('.line')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
  .attr('fill', function(d,i){      
    return colors[i%colors.length];
  })
    .attr("d", line);
```

Thing is I need to set the domains based on the data. I've tried doing:

```
.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.amount; })))
```

...when creating my linear scale but obviously this doesn't work as the array map in the call above just maps out the nested arrays instead of the objects inside.

How do I set the domain using data in this format? Or is there a better way to structure my data whilst still allowing for multiple areas to be drawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the overall extent of all the `amount` values contained in both arrays you need to somehow merge these arrays into one. There are several ways this could be done:

1. [`d3.merge()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_merge) to merge both arrays into one:

   ```
   var allValues = d3.merge(data);
   ```

   The main advantage of this approach over the following ones is the fact, that this will work with any number of nested arrays in `data` without any changes to the code.
2. Built-in method [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

   ```
   var allValues = data[0].concat(data[1])
   ```
3. If you want to show off and don't need to be [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility) with older version of JavaScript, you can apply the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) new to ES6:

   ```
   var allValues = [...data[0], ...data[1]];
   ```

Having this flattened array containing all values you can pass it to `d3.extent()` to calculate the overall extent.

```
var extent = d3.extent(allValues, function(d) { return d.amount; });
```

```js
var data =  [
  [{'year':0,'amount':2},{'year':1,'amount':3},{'year':2,'amount':9},{'year':3,'amount':5},{'year':4,'amount':6},{'year':5,'amount':7},{'year':6,'amount':8},{'year':7,'amount':9},{'year':8,'amount':10},{'year':9,'amount':11},{'year':10,'amount':12}],
  [{'year':0,'amount':1},{'year':1,'amount':2},{'year':2,'amount':8},{'year':3,'amount':4},{'year':4,'amount':5},{'year':5,'amount':6},{'year':6,'amount':7},{'year':7,'amount':8},{'year':8,'amount':9},{'year':9,'amount':10},{'year':10,'amount':11}]
];

console.log(d3.extent(d3.merge(data), function(d) { return d.amount; }));           // using d3.merge()
console.log(d3.extent(data[0].concat(data[1]), function(d) { return d.amount; }));  // using Array.prototype.concat()

// This will only work in compatible browsers which support the new ES6 spread operator
console.log(d3.extent([...data[0], ...data[1]], function(d) { return d.amount; })); // using ES6 spread operator
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MikeRifgin I did a rework of my answer offering even more options to get the desired result.